# SpriteKit crossFadeWithDuration: between scenes not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, transition, scene, sprite-kit

I'm trying to perfrom a simple crossfade transition between scenes in my sprite kit project with the following code:

```
SKTransition *crossFade = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:1.0f];
[self.view presentScene:game transition: crossFade];
```

from a method of my main scene.

Here's what happens:

1. The game scene appears instantly over the current scene.
2. The game scene fades out in 1 second revealing the underlying current scene.
3. The game scene appears instantly over the current scene.

And here's what i expected to happen:

1. The game scene fades in over the underlying current scene

I tested this also in other projects (like [this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/working-with-sktransition/)) and i obtain the same behaviour.

Is the transition working as intended or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you log the view's `scene` property just before calling `presentScene:transition:`, do you get the current scene printed out?

Comment: I get the same effect (replaced one of my existing scene transitions with cross fade), this seems to be a bug. You should report it as a bug to apple with a simple test project: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @Guy Kogus I didn't try yet, I will try asap, but what should I expect by doing that?

Comment: That the current scene is printed out. I was wondering that you might be calling the swap more than once. If you're experiencing this in multiple projects, as is happening to @LearnCocos2D, then file a bug report. I recently abandoned SpriteKit for Cocos2D because of all the bugs.

Comment: And I recently went back to Windows because of all the bugs in Mavericks.

Comment: so don't upgrade from mavericks until a 2nd major update ? or are you having a laugh :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. Use a breakpoint and make sure you are only calling it once. If it is in the update function or something similar then it could be being called twice. If it's only called once, check the code in the Scene you're moving to. You might not initialise it properly and/or call the presentation of the previous scene.

Comment: I think this is definitely a bug since it occurs in different projects by different people.
I already checked my code, thanks anyway!